# why this code isn't working in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using tail -f to fetch log file and output of log this command is input to grep command with search for "ERROR" string and output of grep is used to create/write into a temporary file(**tmpLog**) .

**command :**

```
tail -f logfile |  grep -n -i "ERROR" > tmpLog
```

**logfile content**

```
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.003
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0033
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.004
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.005
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.006
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.007
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0023
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0043
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.004
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.005
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.006
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.007
100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0043
```

Issue is , i am not getting content in tmpLog file , although it is created but with empty content
But when i try this

tail -f logfile | grep -n -i "ERROR"  *> tmpLog

i have **content in tmpLog**

```
a.sh:21:    tail -f logfile |  grep -n -i "ERROR" > tmpLog &  #> /dev/null
logfile:1:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.003
logfile:2:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0033
logfile:3:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.004
logfile:4:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.005
logfile:5:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.006
logfile:6:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.007
logfile:7:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0023
logfile:8:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0043
logfile:9:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.004
logfile:10:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.005
logfile:11:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.006
logfile:12:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.007
logfile:13:100.66.230.2 - - [03/Apr/2017:11:40:23 +0900] "ERROR /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26238 0.0043
```

but i am getting this line **a.sh:21:    tail -f logfile |  grep -n -i "ERROR" > tmpLog &  #> /dev/null** over the top of log which i don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a file called `a.sh` in the working directory?

Is line 21 of this file:

> tail -f logfile |  grep -n -i "ERROR" > tmpLog &  #> /dev/null

The reason you seem to get this is because in your second example, you are effectively running:

```
grep -n -i "ERROR" * > tmpLog
```

which captures all lines in the current directory containing *`ERROR`*.

`tail -f` is effectively an endless stream, and as such not appropriate to redirect into a file in the way that you seem to use it.

You may want to look at [this SU post](https://superuser.com/a/59518/598003) about how buffering causes a problem in redirecting the output.

Comment: Yes i do have . i got you . Thanks